# How to parse a file by certain words?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to parse a file coming from a request I made on a website. So the file look like this

```
id="case8-7"
autocomplete="0"
/></td>
<td
headers="ligne
9,
colonne
9.
Valeur
fixée"
class="tdd"><input
type="text"
readonly
name="sudoku[8][8]"
value="2"
class="chiffre-zoom"
```

The thing is that I only want the ligne with `name="sudoku` and the line juste after `value=`.
The file is longer than this and the condition for me is, if my line is equal to `name=sudoku` so I want this line and the next one only.

Here my code for the moment

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.e-sudoku.fr/grille-de-sudoku.php")
r= r.text
file = open("Sudoku.txt", "w")
file.write(r)
file.close

with open("Sudoku.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if "name=\"sudoku" in word:
                print(word)
```

So I can get sudoku line but I'm missing the next one.

Comment: You can use Beautifulsoup for scraping this will make it so much easier

Comment: To parse HTML, use a HTML parser - you can't rely on newlines and whitespaces in HTML (nor XML nor JSON etc). BeautifulSoup is indeed a good suggestion as it knows how to deal with broken HTML (which is alas the norm).

Answer (score 1):

you better not to use this way
find something specific in the next line that is target and get out your data by
BeautifulSoup library

Answer (score 1):

I would just do something quick and dirty if you only need everything after that do

r.split(‘name=\"sudoku"‘)[1]

Then write that to file